# url not loading in android

Tags: android, web

Hello this is my code

```
String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%%3ASearch&search="+q.getAuthor().replace(" ","%20")+"";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

but it is not showing the result instead it shows web page you requested is temporarily down

is there anything wrong with the code or what

thanks in advance...

Comment: Does your application has `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in the manifest?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov lol, what for ?

Comment: i have all necessary permissions added . i am trying to search the info from wiki for. i think there is something wrong with these line or url cos it works for iphone..

Comment: Have you tried calling the web browser and loading from there, just to check?

Comment: Sorry, I inattentively read the code, there is no need in INTERNET permission. What do you get in `url`? I've tried your code and it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He shouldn't need the Internet permission since this is just launching an intent that the browser is going to pick up.

my guess is either that your device is offline (no 3g/4g, and no wifi) or your url is not working correctly.

make a log statement that prints your url before you parse it to a uri. Then copy the url out of your log and paste it into a browser and see if it loads.

You might consider not doing the urlencoding manually with `String.replace();`

Java provides you with [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) which has static methods that will handle the encoding for you.

Just encode all of your parameter and then append them to your base url.